# Confused by HTML relative root directory and index page when inserting image

Tags: html

I have made my first html document with the basic structure of html.

I am attempting to learn how to use relative pathways when inserting an image into the html document:

- I have saved this document as `filename.html`, in a folder called `web_pages`.
- There is an image in a folder called `new_images`.
- The `new_images` and `web_pages` folders are inside the `project` folder.
- The image is saved as a gif file with the name `first_image`.

When I view the page, the content is successfully showing. However the only thing that is showing for the image is the alternative text.

So I am assuming the pathway i'm using is incorrect?

I have the tag as:

```
<img scr="../new_images/first_image.gif"
 alt="alternative text!"
 style ="width 200px; height 300px;">
```

I have attempt some alternative pathways with use of `../../`

I also tried moving both the first html file and the image to the same folder to see if that would work, and changing the `img` tag to match the new location.

I have put them in their own folders and attempt the above link

I have looked at each title numerous times to make sure the names in the link are identical to what my image and file are called.

- Is it because there needs to be a starting point that I am missing?
- Is it because I haven't created an index page?
- When it comes to the "root directory" does that have to be created at a certain location where all projects should be started at on my computer? (I'm trying to avoid using c:// which I believe is an absolute pathway)
- Do I need the index page? If so: is the index page the first page that will be viewed that a user will go to when they enter the web address?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I did my best to reformat this to make it more readable, including removal of all the stuff about you being new - there's no need for that. Also - you asked a lot of questions, many of them different versions of the same question. This really makes it more difficult to answer (and to even understand). Lastly: You had several irrelevant tags, which I removed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just made a typo entering this question but... your image source attribute is spelled `scr` when it should actually be `src`.

Also, you omitted the `:` in your height and width attributes. It should look more like:

```
<img src="../new_images/first_image.gif"
 alt="alternative text!"
 style ="width: 200px; height: 300px;">
```

Comment: Thank you yeah I looked over it again and like a dummy I made the typo , as soon as I looked at that I feel pretty silly